# How can I debug XAML Exception

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Im using C#/XAML and developing a Windows Store App.

My app is connected to a WCF service.

So I have a listView from wich the user can add and remove Controls from.
When the listView is empty the user can drag the view from FullView to Snapped/Portrait/Filled views with no problems.
But when the user adds an Item to it (Wich is a Control) and then decides to Snap the page the application crashes highlighting this in my App.g.i.cs file:

[image]

When I have a look into the Locals I see:

[image]

And in my reference class:

[image]

Is there something wrong in my XAML file?
Or is there something that needs to be changed in my WCF?

Regards 
Niklas